# WPF binding to a global variable to update UI

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm

Let's say I have two windows and a trayicon context menu.  Each of the windows has a togglebutton and the context menu has a checkable menu item.  All three controls are designed to display and toggle the status of the same value.

How can I bind, in this case IsChecked, of the three controls to a single global variable that when one of the controls is checked/unchecked that the other controls will update accordingly?  Should I just do an invoke or is there an MVVM solution?  I'm new to WPF so I'm not sure the best/most correct way to accomplish this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets say you have WindowA, WindowB, ..., WindowN and assume that they all are of different type.

Create a class, lets say CommonState, that encapsulates all common properties, commands, etc. and **implements INotifyPropertyChanged**

```
public class CommonState : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    private bool _isChecked;

    public bool IsChecked
    {
        get { return _isChecked; }
        set
        {
            if (value != _isChecked)
            {
                _isChecked = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

Then declare an interface:

```
public interface ICommonStateWindow
{
    CommonState { get; set; }
}
```

Make each window implement this interface:

```
public partial class WindowA : Window, ICommonState
{
    public WindowA()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    // This property will be injected, do not re-assign
    public CommonState CommonState { get; set; }
}
```

Inject the common state in each window prior to showing it, for example:

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    private CommonState _state;

    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        _state = new CommonState() {IsChecked = true};

        var wndA = new WindowA() { CommonState = _state };
        var wndB = new WindowB() { CommonState = _state };

        wndA.Show();
        wndB.Show();
    }
}
```

Remember to keep at least one reference to the created CommonState in some long living object (like App or the main window), so it does not get garbage collected at some point.

In the XAML you should bind using a RelativeSource, so that each new type of window you create can have its own independent ViewModel (DataContext):

```
<Window x:Class="Example.WindowA"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="WindowA" Height="300" Width="300">
    <Grid>
        <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding CommonState.IsChecked, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

The example, I've demonstrated is not the only way and I won't say "the best", but it solves the following problems:

1. Encapsulates the common (shared) state
2. Synchronizes the state between different instances (or types) of windows
3. Allows the CommonState to be extended independently of the window implementation (only the XAML needs to be updated)

*Another possible solution is to register a singleton instance of the CommonState   into a statically exposed inversion of control container (IoC) and make each concrete window's ViewModel obtain an instance to it. In this way you will avoid the injection step. This would be an overkill for small projects*

I anyone is trying to run the above code, remember to remove StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml" from App.xaml

Comment: This works great so far between the two windows.  How can I inject the CommonState into a XAML defined ContextMenu?  I'm using Hardcodet.Wpf.TaskbarNotification TaskbarIcon library. The ContextMenu is defined in a XAML ResourceDictionary. TaskbarIcon is created by FindResource during App.OnStartup.

Comment: Add properties like  ICommand CommandA { get; set; } in CommonState and initialize the commands. Then bind the commands like this: <MenuItem Header="CommandA", Command="{Binding CommonState.CommandA, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}"/>

Comment: I'm getting an error: Cannot find source for binding with reference 'RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType='System.Windows.Window', AncestorLevel='1''. BindingExpression:Path=CommonState.IsCheck1; DataItem=null; target element is 'MenuItem' (Name='mnuCheck1'); target property is 'Command' (type 'ICommand'). 
Here's more details:
<ResourceDictionary ... x:Class="MyApp.NotifyIconResources">
...
<MenuItem Command={} />
</ResourceDirectory>

public partial class NotifyIconResources : ResourceDictionary, ICommonState { (MenuEventHandlers) }  How can the RD get a CommonState reference?

Answer (score 0):

You can add to your codebehind bool IsChecked property and use it for all component you want. And you can change it components' event method to true or false.

Comment: Not quite following.  How does it all link together so a change by one component updates all others?